# Select Users in a Specific Row, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to select users from my database that do not have a specific role in entity framework.

My Method is:

```
public IList<Employee> GetPotentialDivisionManagers(Guid companyId)
{
    IList<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    var potentialEmployees = new List<Employee>();

    employees = _dataContext.Set<Employee>()
                .Where(e => e.CompanyId == companyId)
                .ToList();

    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {

      if(!_userManager.IsInRole(employee.Id, "DivisionManager"))
            potentialEmployees.Add(employee);
    }
    return potentialEmployees;
}
```

The Line:

```
if(!_userManager.IsInRole(employee.Id, "DivisionManager"))
```

always crashes with

> "A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set to the association's principal object. The principal object must be tracked and not marked for deletion."

My Employee model inherits from IdentityUser and uses the Id key as the primary key.

```
public class Employee : IdentityUser
{
    ....
}
```

I do not understand how EF sees the query below as an attempt to alter the PK. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity userManager.IsInRole](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585781/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-usermanager-isinrole)

Comment: Also you should tag the question with `asp.net-identity` if that is what you are using and include the version number. If its another framework then tag that.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried setting LazyLoading to on as in the provided link, but my error still persists.

Comment: This may not seem that helpful, but when I query the asp.net identity stuff, I just write stored procedures - it's easier and quicker to obtain the answers you want without having to navigate the user manager and a dbcontext etc etc. it's also easier to tie in your domain specific stuff into the user stuff