# `[Authorize (Roles="Role")]` not working, User.IsInRole("Role") always false

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I feel like I'm missing something. `Authorize` by itself works, but using roles does not. The cshtml-Code contains `razor` stuff, which I'm not sure I'm allowed to use in combination with roles based authorization. Furthermore, `IsInRole` always returns false.

In my database in the table `AspNetUserRoles`, the role instance is there with the correct RoleId and UserId. I added the user to the role in the `Seed` method of the database.

```
if (!userManager.IsInRole(adminUser.Id, "SystemAdministrator"))
            userManager.AddToRole(adminUser.Id, "SystemAdministrator");
```

Do I need to add them somewhere else, like in some kind of role manager?

Here's what I think is the relevant part of the Configuration in Startup:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<RoleManager<AppRole>>((options, context) =>
            new RoleManager<AppRole>(
                new RoleStore<AppRole>(context.Get<MyANTon.DataContext.AntContext>())));
```

Maybe, after this, I have to add the user to the role?

**Edit:** I found a possible error source for this. My `db context` does not seem to include the identity tables like `AspNetUserRoles` or even `AspNetUsers`. I migrated from Forms-Authentication to Identities last week, this is probably the problem now. Do I have to change the context accordingly? It inherits from `IdentityDbContext<AppUser>`, which is why I can't just add the `AspUser`stuff (since it's already there), but when I look at the context at runtime, it's not there...

**Next edit:** I was missing the `web.config` for my role manager. After adding it, it seems like my `data context` idea actually feels to be true. Now, the error thrown is: `'The entity type AppUser is not part of the model for the current context.'`. My context inherits from `IdentityDbContext<AppUser>`, why doesn't it contain `AppUser` then?

Context class:

```
public class AntContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AntContext>(null);
        modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().ToTable("AppUsers");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

UserManager constructor call in controller:

```
        private UserManager<AppUser> userManager = new UserManager<AppUser>(new UserStore<AppUser>());
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating your roles ... make sure there are no extra spaces before or after the Role Name when you save them into the DB. I wasted 3/4 of a day trying to chase down why this was happening.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I actually did that. They are there in the DB (table `AspNetRoles`). There's also nothing wrong with commenting on old questions!

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you have **"SystemAdministrator"** role and may be many others.

You should use `[Authorize(Roles = "RoleName")]`

ex:- `[Authorize(Roles = "SystemAdministrator")]`

Cross verify in your database if you have the corresponding roles.

Comment: In my database, a role "SystemAdministrator" in the table `AspNetRoles` exists. in the table `AspNetUserRoles`, the Admin user is there with their Id and the correct RoleId. To be clear, I am using `[Authorize (Roles ="SystemAdministrator")]`, unlike in the headline which I made more generic.

Comment: Do you mean adding new roles to the database? Not sure, but doing `AddToRole` for the user in the controller does nothing, it's still not considered in this role.

Comment: var _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context));
UserManager.AddToRole("UserName", "UserRole");

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes/

Comment: This does not work either. I try adding the user to the role by ID (which does not crash, meaning it worked) and it still says that the user does not have the role.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585781/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-usermanager-isinrole

Comment: This did not help, but thanks! I think my problem is that in my data context which inherits from IdentityUser, the tables Identity uses are not recognized. The context does not seem to contain all the necessary role data. I added identities just a few days ago after previously having worked with FormsAuth.